# Trying to call a number from another class and display it via jlabel

Tags: java, swing, gaussian

Hello there im having a little problem here, i am trying to call a random number generated in another class and display it via jlabel in 2nd class (jform) and i am sort of lost. number generating is double. 
code

```
GaussianGenerator num = new GaussianGenerator();//calling another class
CriminalDetails() 
{
    initComponents();
    double number = 0;
    num.GaussianGenerator(number);
    CriminalID.setText(Double.toString(number));//CriminalID jfield
}
```

The number im getting on jfield is the 0 initialized in "double number" but i want to get number generated in GaussianGenerator class. 
Thank you for having a look and your time, help appreciated.

Comment: does the GaussianGenerator class return a value? shouldn't you assign a value to the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

num is an instance of the number generator. You should be setting the value of number by calling a method on the instance of the number generator object and assigning it to number. Like this (I am not familiar with your other class):

```
GaussianGenerator num = new GaussianGenerator();//calling another class
CriminalDetails() 
{
    initComponents();
    double number = 0;
    number = num.getNextValue();
    CriminalID.setText(Double.toString(number));//CriminalID jfield
}
```

Or is GaussianGenerator is also the name of the method? Bad idea from a design standpoint. Rather than passing it to the method as a paremeter, the method should just return the generated value:

numer = num.GaussianGenerator();

In Java you can't pass a primitive by reference if that is what you are trying to do. You can do this with objects (e.g. Double), however, but that is bad design since a double will suffice. You should also read a good tutorial on Java coding conventions so you can learn how to properly name and capitalize methods. So you would see that this is better coding:

```
number = num.getNextValue();
```

Comment: I am actually calling a method, however do you recon that same class name and method name will interfere ??
public class GaussianGenerator 
{  
    public double GaussianGenerator(double number)
    {

Comment: Yes, the error is that you are passing a primitive in and trying to set its value, which you can't do and why its value is still zero after the call. You have to return the primitive. The method is improperly named and capitalized, but that is an aside.

Comment: Seems like we had both same though in mind about class and method name being the same and that would cause problems. All now solver i just renamed Method name and it now works properly :)

Comment: Actually, the Java compiler will allow you to name a method the same as the constructor. Most compilers will flag it with a warning, but it is allowed. Of course, it is not a good idea to do so. Your problem is that you were trying to assign to passed in primitive, rather than returning the value and assigning it to the primitive.

Comment: Well NetBeans is not even bothered to flag it with warning ;) anyway thank you for your time :) appreciate it